# Different behavior of subprocess.Popen and os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x, tortoisesvn

I faced different behavior of subprocess.Popen and os.system in Python 3.3

When I run in command prompt

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\projects\my_project" /closeonend:0
```

TortioseSVN tries to update my folder. When I try to make such system call from python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["TortoiseProc.exe", "/command:update", '/path:"C:\projects\my_project"', '/closeonend:0'])
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["TortoiseProc.exe", "/command:update", '/path:"C:\projects\my_project"', '/closeonend:0'])
```

TortoiseProc.exe is called ok, but it is not updating folder - it shows that it is skipped.

When I use os.system - everything works fine, TortoiseProc.exe is updating my folder but console window appears also.

```
os.system('TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\projects\my_project" /closeonend:0')
```

So how can I make TortoiseProc.exe work through subprocess? I how to call os.system without console window?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, since the parameter strings appear to be the same, but it is safer to use raw strings when there are \ (backslashes) in the text, otherwise the following character will be escaped.  e.g. `r'Tortoise....'`

Comment: @cdarke - I've tried it - it doesn't help